# Having an issue while getting my dev tool setup(webpack)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, webpack

I am trying to learn modern js using webpack and babel. i am a beginner to this stuff. the instructor teaches modern js by creating an app called forkify- a recipe app..and i am trying to get it to work . but after running npm install webpack cli and then npm run dev, npm run build ..everything works fine up to this point..but after running npm run start, it displays this error.Can anyone help me with this issue:??

```html
user@Users-MacBook-Pro forkify % npm run start                      
> forkify@1.0.0 start /Users/user/Desktop/forkify
> webpack-dev-server --mode development --open

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- /Users/user/Desktop/forkify/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/forkify/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/user/Desktop/forkify/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! forkify@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2020-10-22T09_59_47_518Z-debug.log
user@Users-MacBook-Pro forkify %
```

Here is my json package:

```html
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "forkify project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "bhat shakran",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
  
}
```

And  my log file:

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v12.19.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~prestart: forkify@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~start: forkify@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/user/Desktop/forkify/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin
9 verbose lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/user/Desktop/forkify
10 silly lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack-dev-server --mode development --open' ]
11 silly lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle forkify@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: forkify@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid forkify@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/user/Desktop/forkify
16 verbose Darwin 19.0.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v12.19.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error forkify@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Have you also runned `npm install` (in order to install all the required npm libraries) ?

Comment: @Berci yes i have

Comment: Than, if the instructor app is working, yours not, and you have all the dependencies, is probably a problem with the versions of the packages. I would recomand to check if you can what node version he is using.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2759) with `webpack-dev-server`. To work around it, use the previous major version of `webpack-cli`:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli@^3
```

What you are asking `npm` to do is install `webpack-cli`, but only use the latest version that satisfies the form `3.X.X`. Visit [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) to learn more.

Unless your tutorial explicitly asks for webpack version 5, you might want to use v4. v5 only came out a few weeks ago and many tutorials have not updated to it. Install v4 just how you did it above:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack@^4
```